# Return query results where two fields are different (Access 2010)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, criteria

I'm working in a large access database (Access 2010) and am trying to return records where two locations are different.

In my case, I have a large number of birds that have been observed on multiple dates and potentially on different islands. Each bird has a unique BirdID and also an actual physical identifier (unfortunately that may have changed over time). [I'm going to try addressing the changing physical identifier issue later]. I currently want to query individual birds where one or more of their observations is different than the "IslandAlpha" (the first island where they were observed). Something along the lines of a criteria for BirdID: WHERE IslandID [doesn't equal] IslandAlpha.

I then need a separate query to find where all observations DO equal where they were first observed. So where IslandID = IslandAlpha

I'm new to Access, so let me know if you need more information on how my tables/relationships are set up! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output. Where is 'IslandAlpha' data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following tables:

1. `Birds` table in which all individual birds have records with a unique `BirdID` and `IslandAlpha`.
2. `Sightings` table in which individual sightings are recorded, including `IslandID`.

Your first query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Birds
INNER JOIN Sightings ON Birds.BirdID=Sightings.BirdID 
WHERE Sightings.IslandID <> Birds.IslandAlpha
```

You second query would be the same but with `=` instead of `<>` in the `WHERE` clause.

Please provide us information about the tables and columns you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I will presume you are asking this question because a simple join of tables and filtering where IslandAlpha <> ObsLoc is not possible because IslandAlpha is derived from first observation record for each bird. Pulling first observation record for each bird requires a nested query. Need a unique record identifier in Observations - autonumber should serve. Assuming there is an observation date/time field, consider:

```
SELECT * FROM Observations WHERE ObsID IN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 ObsID FROM Observations AS Dupe 
     WHERE Dupe.ObsBirdID = Observations.ObsBirdID ORDER BY Dupe.ObsDateTime);
```

Now use that query for subsequent queries.

```
SELECT * FROM Observations 
INNER JOIN Query1 ON Observations.ObsBirdID = Query1.ObsBirdID 
WHERE Observations.ObsLocID <> Query1.ObsLocID;
```